# Is it possible combine fx:include and afterburner

Tags: javafx, fxml

I currently using afterburner.fx to tailor together components of JavaFX based application.
Right now I trying move components in separate fxml files for more comfortable maintenance.

To load such components I using *fx:include* directive which allow load nested components automatically.

Problem is that with automatic load I loosing possibility get presenter from nested view.

Is there a way to combine automatic load and in same time, be able work with nested components from parent root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two seem to work fine together.

Afterburner works by setting a controller factory on the FXML loader, which takes care of instantiating the presenter class and injecting values into it.

The `<fx:include>` element will propagate the controller factory when loading the included FXML, so you can also inject values into the controller defined in the included FXML. Because afterburner effectively uses a singleton scope for injection, the same instance of injected fields will be used. This means you can readily share your data model between the different presenter classes.

If you want access to the presenter associated with the included FXML, just use the [standard technique for "nested controllers"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).

So, for example:

main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="application.MainPresenter">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="First Name" prefWidth="150">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Last Name" prefWidth="150">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Email" prefWidth="200">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="email" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <fx:include source="Editor.fxml" fx:id="editor">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" bottom="5" left="5" right="5"/>
            </padding>
        </fx:include>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

editor.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" hgap="5" vgap="10" fx:controller="application.EditorPresenter">
    <Label GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="First Name:"/>
    <TextField fx:id="firstNameTextField" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>

    <Label GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="Last Name"/>
    <TextField fx:id="lastNameTextField" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>

    <Label GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="Email"/>
    <TextField fx:id="emailTextField" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>

    <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
        <Button fx:id="addEditButton" onAction="#addEdit" />
    </HBox>

</GridPane>
```

MainPresenter.java:

```
package application;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class MainPresenter {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> table ;

    // This is the controller (presenter) for the included fxml
    // It is injected by the FXMLLoader; the rule is that "Controller" needs to be
    // appended to the fx:id attribute of the <fx:include> tag.
    // This is not used in this example but is here to demonstrate how to access it
    // if needed.
    @FXML
    private EditorPresenter editorController ;

    @Inject
    private DataModel dataModel ;

    public void initialize() {
        table.setItems(dataModel.getPeople());

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> dataModel.setCurrentPerson(newPerson));

        dataModel.currentPersonProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (newPerson == null) {
                table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            } else {
                table.getSelectionModel().select(newPerson);
            }
        });

        dataModel.getPeople().addAll(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );
    }
}
```

EditorPresenter.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class EditorPresenter {
    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameTextField ;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameTextField ;
    @FXML
    private TextField emailTextField ;
    @FXML
    private Button addEditButton ;

    @Inject
    private DataModel dataModel ;

    public void initialize() {
        addEditButton.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(Bindings.isNull(dataModel.currentPersonProperty()))
                .then("Add")
                .otherwise("Update")
        );

        dataModel.currentPersonProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (newPerson == null) {
                firstNameTextField.setText("");
                lastNameTextField.setText("");
                emailTextField.setText("");
            } else {
                firstNameTextField.setText(newPerson.getFirstName());
                lastNameTextField.setText(newPerson.getLastName());
                emailTextField.setText(newPerson.getEmail());
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void addEdit() {
        Person person = dataModel.getCurrentPerson();
        String firstName = firstNameTextField.getText();
        String lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();
        String email = emailTextField.getText();
        if (person == null) {
            dataModel.getPeople().add(new Person(firstName, lastName, email));
        } else {
            person.setFirstName(firstName);
            person.setLastName(lastName);
            person.setEmail(email);
        }
    }
}
```

MainView.java:

```
package application;

import com.airhacks.afterburner.views.FXMLView;

public class MainView extends FXMLView {

}
```

Main.java (application class):

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.airhacks.afterburner.injection.Injector;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MainView mainView = new MainView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainView.getView(), 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        Injector.forgetAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

DataModel.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class DataModel {
    private final ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObjectProperty<Person> currentPerson = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "currentPerson");

    public ObservableList<Person> getPeople() {
        return people ;
    }

    public final Person getCurrentPerson() {
        return currentPerson.get();
    }

    public final void setCurrentPerson(Person person) {
        this.currentPerson.set(person);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Person> currentPersonProperty() {
        return currentPerson ;
    }
}
```

And the usual Person.java example:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
    public final String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }
    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName ;
    }

    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
    public final String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }
    public final void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName ;
    }

    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");
    public final String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }
    public final void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email.set(email);
    }
    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email ;
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEmail(email);
    }
}
```